# Skip and Limit on nested array element

Tags: arrays, mongodb, multidimensional-array, mongoose

I want to apply skip and limit for paging in nested array of a document how can I perform this [Efficient Way]

My Document recored like

```
{
   "_id":"",
   "name":"",
   "ObjectArray":[{
       "url":"",
       "value":""
   }]
}
```

I want to retrieve multiple document and every document contain 'n' number of record.

I am using `$in` in find query to retrieve multiple record on basis of _id but how can i get certain number of element of `ObjectArray`  in every document?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can try like this -

```
db.collection.find({}, {ObjectArray:{$slice:[0, 3]}})
```

This will provide you records from `0..3`

`$slice:[SKIP_VALUE, LIMIT_VALUE]}`

For your example:-

```
db.collection.find({"_id":""}, {ObjectArray:{$slice:[0, 3]}})
```

Here is the reference for MongoDB Slice feature.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/

Comment: Why doesn't this query work in Mongo Compass?
Is there any alternative to write above query in Mongo Compass?