# Skip and limit on mongoose model sub-document/array

Tags: express, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mern

I recently started learning express and mongoose, but I'm not sure if I should be doing things the way I am. I followed a tutorial to handle posts, each post can have likes and comments, my model looks like this one from the tutorial.
[Mongoose Post Model](https://github.com/bradtraversy/devconnector_2.0/blob/master/models/Post.js)

But I want lazy load my comments (like a Facebook post) when I open a post using skip and limit, the question is should I have the comments on another document or can I skip and limit inside of those comments?

Post.find({ id: req.params.id, comments: {skip: 0, limit: 10}})???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this answer: [Skip and Limit on nested array element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30222469/skip-and-limit-on-nested-array-element)

As the example, you should use SLICE

```
db.collection.find({}, {ObjectArray:{$slice:[0, 3]}})
```